# why is this method of calculating the probability of an ace wrong?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, conditional-probability, card-games

**Problem:** A deck of cards is shuffled and then divided into two halves of 26 cards each. A card is drawn from one of the halves; it turns out to be an ace. The ace is then placed in the second half-deck. The half is then shuffled, and a card is drawn from it. Compute the probability that this drawn card is an ace.

**My attempt:**

to randomly divide the cards into two halves $A$ and $B$, I followed this process.
Put each ace, in either $A$ or $B$, with  equal probability.(ex. the ace of spades goes into set A with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, and into set B with probability $\frac{1}{2})$
Then, divide the remaining 48 cards between $A$ and $B$, such that both sets of cards contain $26$ cards each.

**Question1**: Does this process, randomly divide the deck of 52 cards into 2 halves?

Without loss of generality assume, $A$ is the first half, and $B$ is the second half.

define $AL = \text{first half contains at least one ace}$ 
and 
$i = \text{first half contains exactly i aces}$, $i\in {1,2,3,4}$

$=>P(AL) = 1 - P(\text{second half contains all aces}) = 1-(0.5)^4 = \frac{15}{16}$
and

$P(0) = \dbinom{4}{0}*(0.5)^0(0.5)^4 = \dfrac{1}{16}$ and $P(0|AL)=\dfrac{P(0\cap AL)}{P(AL)} = 0$

$P(1) = \dbinom{4}{1}*(0.5)^1(0.5)^3 = \dfrac{1}{4}$ and $P(1|AL)=\dfrac{P(1\cap AL)}{P(AL)} = \dfrac{P(1)}{P(AL)} = \dfrac{4}{15}$

$P(2) = \dbinom{4}{2}*(0.5)^2(0.5)^2 = \dfrac{3}{8}$ and $P(2|AL)=\dfrac{P(2\cap AL)}{P(AL)} = \dfrac{P(2)}{P(AL)} = \dfrac{2}{5} = \dfrac{6}{15}$

$P(3) = \dbinom{4}{3}*(0.5)^3(0.5)^1 = \dfrac{1}{4}$ and $P(3|AL)=\dfrac{P(3\cap AL)}{P(AL)} = \dfrac{P(3)}{P(AL)} = \dfrac{4}{15}$

$P(4) = \dbinom{4}{4}*(0.5)^4(0.5)^0 = \dfrac{1}{16}$ and $P(4|AL)=\dfrac{P(4\cap AL)}{P(AL)} = \dfrac{P(4)}{P(AL)} = \dfrac{1}{15}$

now, if there are $i$ aces in $A$, then after an ace is selected from $A$ and transferred to $B$, $B$ will contain $4-i+1=5-i$ aces, and a total of $27$ cards.
define $C = \text{card selected from B is an ace}$

$=>P(C|i) = \dfrac{5-i}{27}$

**Question2:** Are the quantities $P(AL)$ and P(i) calculated correctly?

$$P(C) = \sum_{i=1}^4 P(i|AL) \cdot P(C|i,AL) = \sum_{i=1}^4 P(i|AL) \cdot P(C|i) = \frac{4}{15}\frac{4}{27} + \frac{6}{15}\frac{3}{27} + \frac{4}{15}\frac{2}{27} + \frac{1}{15}\frac{1}{27} = \frac{43}{15 \cdot 27} = \frac{129}{45 \cdot 27}$$

The given answer is $\frac{129}{51 \cdot 27}$, what have I done wrong?

**edit:** correct ways for solving the problem are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2814030/415432) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/71068/415432), I am not asking for these

Comment: To answer question 1: No, it doesn't. To see why that is think that a random half deck can contain 4 aces. But with your method that is impossible.

Comment: it is certainly possible. I have added an example for more clarification.

Comment: Now that you clarified it's ok. But probably not necessary.

Comment: The probability that half A has four aces is not $1/16$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I'm assuming you mean $P(4)$. why so?

Comment: If your method was truly random you would have $$P(4)=\frac{ \binom{48}{22}}{\binom{52}{26}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not appropriate to use the binomial distribution for the aces, since the location of each ace is not independent.

The probability that the Ace of Hearts is in deck A is...
$$ P(H)= \frac{\binom{51}{25} }{ \binom{52}{26}   } =\frac 12$$

But the probability that the ace of spades is in deck A **given that the ace of hearts is in deck A** is

$$ P(S|H)= \frac{\binom{50}{24} }{ \binom{51}{25}   } =\frac{25}{51} <\frac 12$$